# White Space Between SVG Background Repeats

Tags: html, css, svg

I cannot seem to get rid of this white space between SVG element repeats (as CSS backgrounds) exported by Illustrator CS5.

I am using a simple CSS `background-image` and `background-repeat: repeat-x` but there is always this white space between each repeat. I am not using `background-size` at all.

Here is what I am seeing (tested on Safari/Chrome):

[image: white space]

If I open the SVG to check for any whitespace on the side, nothing is there (see window on the right) and it goes all the way to the side of the window:

[image: no white space on separate window]

I've tried saving the image in Illustrator by `File -> Scripts -> SaveDocsAsSVG` and `Save as.. -> SVG`.

HTML

```
<body>
    <div class="outer">
        <div class="inner">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
.outer {
  background-color: #7fcefb;
  height: 700px;
  background-image: url('/wp-content/themes/grizzly/assets/img/trees.png');
  background-position: center 95%;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
}

.inner {
  background-image: url('/wp-content/themes/grizzly/assets/svg/treeshill.svg');
  height: 700px;
  background-position: center bottom;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
```

Comment: Can you post your code or a link? It looks like something might have a slight margin or padding on it.

Comment: can you post the link to the image?

Comment: Added some basic HTML and CSS to show the setup. SVG download - http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=02705325478483063668

Answer (score 43, accepted):

If it's what I think it is, open up your SVG file and change the root `<svg>` element so that it includes the following attribute:

```
<svg ... preserveAspectRatio="none">
```

If it already has a `preserveAspectRatio` attribute, just change it to `"none"` and reload.

Comment: Paul - you are the man! Thank you! Does this have to be added because browsers automatically modify the aspect ratio slightly?

Comment: It will be because there is a slight difference between the aspect ratio of your `width`/`height` attributes and the width & height values in your `viewBox` attribute.

Comment: Thanks so much, was bashing my head against this for a long time!

Comment: Thanks a lot, you've made my day!

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem. In all scenarios that I can possibly come up with to test, a repeating SVG with preserveAspectRatio set to none still has white space in between it in all modern browsers at (seemingly) random zoom levels.

Comment: Ask a question if you are having trouble. But first check some things. (1) make sure that your viewBox is not slightly bigger than your contents. (2) Also try rounding coordinates at the edges. EG. 123.456 -> 123 etc. (paths and viewBox).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56309871/svg-as-a-css-background-is-there-any-way-to-repeat-x-with-no-space-in-between

Answer (score 8):

`preserveAspectRatio="none"` didn't work for me because it makes the svg to take the full width of its parent container.

Instead a take the parameters: `preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMax meet"` which in return I was able to use with `background-repeat: repeat-x;`

For more info here is an exellent article: [A Look At preserveAspectRatio in SVG](http://codepen.io/jonitrythall/post/preserveaspectratio-in-svg)

Comment: With `preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMax meet"` I still see gaps. Though `preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMax slice"` works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I can't guarantee this will always work or even work in your situation, but you might try specifying the css background-size in pixels not as a percentage. This has worked for me in the past with chrome. i.e. background-size: 50px 100px;