# SVG as a CSS Background - Is there ANY way to repeat-x with NO space in between?

Tags: css, svg

In Webkit and Blink-based browsers, SVGs do not tile correctly. There is a space between the images at various zoom levels. There are a number of topics on StackOverflow addressing this, all marked as solved, but those people must not have tested their solutions thoroughly enough.

My SVGs are a perfectly even number of pixels (130 x 24).
They have background-size set to 130px 24px.
They are set to preserveAspectRatio="none".
There is absolutely zero empty space on the edges of the SVG.

Yet, while it looks fine at 100%, there is still a thin space between the SVGs if you zoom in to the right level.

It surprises me this bug has not been reported before, given the widespread recommendations of using SVGs for backgrounds.

Here is the exact SVG:

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
      viewBox="0 0 130 24" xml:space="preserve" preserveAspectRatio="none">
    <style type="text/css">
     .st0{fill:#A5EF8B;}
    </style>
    <path class="st0" d="M0,12c32.5,0,32.5,12,65,12s32.5-12,65-12V0C97.5,0,92.9,12,65,12C32.5,12,20.7,0,0,0"/>
    </svg>
```

I can confirm this behavior with other SVGs as well, such as the ones at https://www.heropatterns.com/

Codepen for testing: https://codepen.io/TelFiRE/pen/gJzqaG

The space between the images is usually sub 1 pixel (meaning the line is just a lighter shade of green). It's subtle and may be hard to see if you have a dull monitor.

In asking this question, I'm hoping to understand WHY it is occurring in a way that lets me make lots of repeating SVG backgrounds without issue. It's not just about the one image, so I want to avoid hacky solutions/workarounds if at all possible. For example, chopping 2 pixels off the edge fixes it 99% of the way, but not entirely, and it leaves me wondering what I would do if I actually needed those two pixels. This particular SVG looks okay like that but more complicated patterns would be knocked out of alignment.

Comment: First: Can you show the CSS for how you set the background? And second: try extending your path so that it is a little wider than your viewBox.  Ie starts at -1 and goes to 131.

Comment: It's set as a background URL to the SVG. Extending the wings off to the sides does not do the trick, also just increases the file size by 30% (bigger than a PNG) so even if it worked, it wouldn't be a solution, unfortunately.

Comment: I added a Codepen to the original question. I tried to originally but couldn't find a long term SVG host. Wasn't thinking about url encoding, thanks to enxaneta for that idea.

Comment: In case you are intrested in a CSS solution to create the shape: https://stackoverflow.com/q/56199721/8620333 .. not perfect as the SVG but can be easy to handle

Comment: That's a cool tip. Ironically, some of those have a very similar issue with a horizontal line appearing at certain zoom levels. I think it might be unrelated though, and fixable. In either case thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It seems that some browsers do have trouble with repeating backgrounds made from SVG images.

One solution to this is to do the repeating inside the SVG instead.  We can use a `<pattern>` element to define the repeating pattern and use that to fill a rectangle.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="24">
  <defs>
    <pattern id="bg" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="130" height="24">
      <path fill="#A5EF8B" d="M0,12c32.5,0,32.5,12,65,12s32.5-12,65-12V0C97.5,0,92.9,12,65,12C32.5,12,20.7,0,0,0"/>
    </pattern>
  </defs>
  <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#bg)"/>
</svg>
```

And when used as a `background-image` to a `<div>`, it becomes:

```css
div {
  margin: 4rem 0;
  height: 24px;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='100%' height='24'%3E%3Cdefs%3E%3Cpattern id='bg' patternUnits='userSpaceOnUse' width='130' height='24'%3E%3Cpath fill='%23A5EF8B' d='M0,12c32.5,0,32.5,12,65,12s32.5-12,65-12V0C97.5,0,92.9,12,65,12C32.5,12,20.7,0,0,0'/%3E%3C/pattern%3E%3C/defs%3E%3Crect width='100%' height='100%' fill='url(%23bg)'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
  background-size: 100% 24px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Looks very promising! Thank you for sharing an elegant solution! Will most likely select this as the best answer after I do a bit of testing.

Comment: Hi, unfortunately, I discovered a new (though most likely related) problem with this solution. At certain zoom levels (in this case, 110% for me seems to be the only one doing it) you can see the SVG repeating for a single pixel on the bottom. See https://codepen.io/TelFiRE/pen/vwzBay

Comment: There's a simple fix for that. Just make the pattern height a little bigger.  Eg. change it to `height='27'`. That will shift the stray pixels off the bottom of the SVG where they won't be visible.  https://codepen.io/PaulLeBeau/pen/vwzLXv

Answer (score 2):

This is your svg used as a css background and there are no gaps. I've encoded the svg using [this tool](https://codepen.io/yoksel/pen/JDqvs)

Also please read [Optimizing SVGs in data URIs](https://codepen.io/tigt/post/optimizing-svgs-in-data-uris)

```css
body{background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg version='1.1' id='Layer_1' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' x='0px' y='0px' viewBox='0 0 130 24' xml:space='preserve' preserveAspectRatio='none'%3E%3Cstyle type='text/css'%3E .st0%7Bfill:%23A5EF8B;%7D %3C/style%3E%3Cpath class='st0' d='M0,12c32.5,0,32.5,12,65,12s32.5-12,65-12V0C97.5,0,92.9,12,65,12C32.5,12,20.7,0,0,0'/%3E%3C/svg%3E%0A");
background-size:130px 24px}
```

#### UPDATE

Apparently in Safari there is a gap between the repetitions of the svg background image. In the next example I'm setting the `background-size:12vw` (or any other multiple of vw) the gaps disappear.

In fact I've simplified the path as well.

```css
body{  
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg version='1.1' id='Layer_1' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' viewBox='0 6 130 26' width='100%' height='100%'%3E%3Cstyle type='text/css'%3E .st0%7Bstroke:%23A5EF8B; fill:none; stroke-width:12;%7D %3C/style%3E%3Cpath class='st0' d='M-1,12c32.5,0,32.5,12,65,12s32.5-12,69-12'/%3E%3C/svg%3E%0A");
background-size:12vw}
```

Comment: I appreciate your response. Unfortunately, though it works in StackOverflow's viewer for some reason, it does not work in practice, still have lines between every repeat: https://codepen.io/TelFiRE/pen/gJzqaG

Comment: Correction, even in StackOverflow's viewer the issue arises at some zoom levels, although it seems to be a rarer occurrence.

Comment: I am able to see the gaps only on Safari. I've updated my answer with an example where I'm using `background-size:12vw` but apparently any other múltiple of `vw` would do. Please take a look.

Comment: The problem is still present in your second example, in Chrome 74.0.3729.169 on Windows 10. Also, the background size needs to be set to 130px 24px. Scaling of the image would be highly undesirable. Starting to think the reality is that modern browsers simply don't support repeating SVGs as backgrounds.

Answer (score 0):

Each svg file has the following properties: "fill" and "stroke".
Fill is a fill, and stroke is a contour. This space is both, which is by default transparencies. Edit the SVG file and add it to  this code:

`.st0 {
    fill: #A5EF8B;
    stroke: #A5EF8B;
    }`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sv7GV.png)

Comment: Still gives me gaps at certain zoom levels. https://codepen.io/TelFiRE/pen/wbXazm

Comment: In the Opera House at the maximum magnification, I have no gap. It always worked for every one of my projects. Try using the `stroke-width : 2px` property and more. Let me know if it helped. [Your link in Opera](http://krzysztof.antosik.co/host/5846734095873.PNG)

Comment: Try to set such a background size:
  
`background-size:129px 24px;`

[https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gJKRgZ](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gJKRgZ)

Comment: Everything works well for me.
I checked on:
Windows: Opera, Chrome, EDGE,
Linux: Firefox
Android: Chrome, Opera Touch
PS4: PS4 Browser

Comment: Here is a screenshot of your codepen in Chrome at 150%: https://imgur.com/a/SH1pXS4

Not only is the issue not fixed, but the solution leaves me very insecure even if it were to work. WHY do I have to chop a pixel off the edge? WHY don't the CSS backgrounds simply tile as they are supposed to?